# Json schema validade for complex structure

Tags: json, jsonschema

Hi I need a help to generate a json schema to validade a form, the follow example is a member array, there is a lot of member types, type 1 is a

project manager,type 2 System analyst and Type 3 is a developer. I need to validade if a project contains a members list with:
minimum 1 and maximum 1 of type 1;
minimum 1 maximum 2 of type 2; 
minimum 2 maximum 2 of type 3.

```
 {
"members": [
    {
        "memberid": 1,
        "membername": "John",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "memberid": 2,
        "membername": "Jack",
        "type": 2
    },
    {
        "memberid": 3,
        "membername": "Peter",
        "type": 3
    },
    {
        "memberid": 4,
        "membername": "Jorge",
        "type": 3
    },
    {
        "memberid": 5,
        "membername": "Clay",
        "type": 3
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough one.  The only limitation of this solution is that it requires that the members be in a particular order.  Also, the schema could grow out of control if additional combinations are required in the future.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "members": { "$ref": "#/definitions/members" }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "members": {
      "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/smallTeam" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/largeTeam" }
      ]
    },
    "smallTeam": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/projectManager" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/systemAnalyst" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/developer" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/developer" }
      ],
      "additionalItems": false
    },
    "largeTeam": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/projectManager" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/systemAnalyst" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/systemAnalyst" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/developer" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/developer" }
      ],
      "additionalItems": false
    },
    "projectManager": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/member" }],
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [1] }
      }
    },
    "systemAnalyst": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/member" }],
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [2] }
      }
    },
    "developer": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/member" }],
      "properties": {
        "type": { "enum": [3] }
      }
    },
    "member": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "memberid": { "type": "integer" },
        "membername": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["memberid", "membername", "type"]
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have control over this structure?  If it was a little different, it would be a lot easier to describe.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "projectManager": { "$ref": "#/definitions/member" },
    "systemAnalyst": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/member" },
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 2
    },
    "developer": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/member" },
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 2
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "member": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "memberid": { "type": "integer" },
        "membername": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```